# Interfaces with templates C++

Tags: c++, generics, interface

I want to make a Interface and make the return type of one of the functions a generic(like in java).
I wrote this:

```
    template <class T>
    class IUnionFind {
    public:
     IUnionFind();

     ///@param[in] x
     ///@param[in] y
     virtual void unionSet(int x,int y)=0;
     ///@param[in]
     virtual void find (int x)=0;
     virtual T  make_set(int x)=0;
     virtual ~IUnionFind(){};
     };
```

And the eclipse compiler does'nt accuse nothing wrong.
However when i make a header to implement the interface like this:

```
    template <class T>
    class UnionFindLinkedList : public IUnionFind {
     public:
     UnionFindLinkedList();
     virtual ~UnionFindLinkedList();
     void unionSet(int x,int y);
     void find (int x);
     T  make_set(int x);
    };
```

IT accuses "excpected class name before "{" token on the line of the class declaration;
If i remove the generic everything goes fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
template <class T>
class UnionFindLinkedList : public IUnionFind<T>
{
   .....
```